# How to rotate sprite based on x coordinates of accelerometer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, cmmotionmanager

My character needs to move and rotate left and right. Moving works all fine, but i am not satisfied with the rotating. I want the character to rotate ONLY when it moves left or right. When the character doesn't move, the rotating needs to stop. Imitating a smooth roll.

I tried rotating through an `SKAction`, see below:

```
if(_shouldMoveToRight) {
    SKAction *moveAction = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(_destX, _destY) duration:1];
    [_character runAction:moveAction];

    SKAction *rotateAction = [SKAction rotateByAngle:0.2 duration:1];
    [_character runAction:rotateAction];
}
if (_shouldMoveToLeft) {
    SKAction *moveAction = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(_destX, _destY) duration:1];
    [_character runAction:moveAction];

    SKAction *rotateAction = [SKAction rotateByAngle:0.2 duration:1];
    [_character runAction:rotateAction];
```

This makes the character moves all time. Any help is appreciated!

Code for moving:

```
self.manager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
if ([self.manager isAccelerometerAvailable] == YES) {
    [self.manager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                                        withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         _destX = 0.0, _destY = 0.0;
         _currentX = _character.position.x;
         _currentY = _character.position.y;

         _shouldMoveToRight = NO;
         _shouldMoveToLeft = NO;

         if(data.acceleration.y < -0.25) { // tilting the device to the right
             _destX = _currentX + (data.acceleration.x * kPlayerSpeed);
             _destY = _currentY;
             _shouldMoveToRight = YES;
             _shouldMoveToLeft = NO;
         } else if (data.acceleration.y > 0.25) { // tilting the device to the left
             _destX = _currentX + (data.acceleration.x * kPlayerSpeed);
             _destY = _currentY;
             _shouldMoveToRight = NO;
             _shouldMoveToLeft = YES;
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: Instead of moveTo,  why not get the difference from last tilt to current tilt,  and do a moveBy.  and for the duration of each move by,  make it 0, because right now you have it set up as 'With each moveTo, take 1 second to reach its destination'

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. Should I implement current and last tilt and remove the rotation action? Yes, you are right, but I found the movement is smoother with the duration on 1.

Comment: ok first part, Right now you are doing the following.  You capture the persons position, then set a variable to the persons position + the change, then calling a moveTo.  Instead of this, you take out the part about reading the persons position, and you just capture the difference in the tilt,  and do a moveBy call instead of a moveTo call.  This will move the player by the difference of the tilt, instead of moving him to a specific point

Comment: second part,  the way runAction works is the actions stack on top of each other,  so you are creating a new run with every move to.  If the first moveTo does not finish, it will run the first moveTo and the second moveTo  concurrently, which is bad.  Setting the duration to 0 means that the first moveTo ends instantly,  and you dont have the person have 2 moving actions running at the same time

Comment: The current and last tilt captures the degree of rotation of the character? Or does it capture the

Comment: movement on the x axis? I don't know what you mean with tilt

Comment: The way rotation works is absolute,  tilt the device all the way to the left, your result is -1, tilt it all the way to the right,  it is 1.  If you are treating your tilt like a joystick,  then what you have is correct,  do not capture the change, just do the moveBy based on the current tilt. But what if your device is tilted all the way to the right, and the user tilts left just slightly,  expecting to go left,  well for this you need relative controls,  so you take your current accelerometer state, and subtract your last accel state.  This will tell you the change that happened with tilt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98142/discussion-between-nielsapp-and-knight0fdragon).